# Make error:no rule to make target for gpu driver

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, device-driver

I want to compile the AMD graphic driver for my E9171 graphic card. I found a driver at Torvalds repository. https://github.com/torvalds/linux/tree/master/drivers/gpu/drm/amd/amdgpu but it's giving

> 'No rule to make target' error.

when I use `make` command.

I checked the makefile, there is nothing like "all:" or "clean:" or "install:"

Any suggestion to compile these c files into .ko file?

Comment: You have to compile the whole kernel... I mean `make menuconfig` -> configure kernel -> `make`. There are many resources available online on how to configure and compile kernel. Most probably you already have the driver compiled in your kernel, are you _sure_ you want to compile it? why? You want specifically `.ko` kernel object file (and why would you want it?) or you want a kernel with the driver?

Comment: @KamilCuk I will use it in another linux distribition created by Yocto project. I don't exactly know how am i gonna do this but trying all the ways I can. I am trying to use this driver in a .bb file as driver source.

Comment: @KamilCuk actually I want a kernel with this driver and put it into my embedded  board